# How to change a font/background color in transparent windows?

Tags: terminal, colors

When you select something, the color of the selection usually changes to the font color, and the font color is being set to backgroud color. So, if you have a black background in a terminal, and the font is orange, you will get an orange selection and a black font color.

What would happen if you had a transparent window, and the transparency was set to 100%? Just take a look at the following pics.

The one with a black background:

[image: pic]

And the transparent one:

[image: pic]

Is there a way to change the font/background color of transparent windows?

Comment: What terminal emulator?

Comment: It's rxvt-unicode-256color

Comment: What setting are you using? Check https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Rxvt-unicode#True_transparency and https://blog.inexplicity.de/urxvt-borderless-and-transparency.html .

Comment: I'm using the one with `[00]#000000`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution. There are two parameters that can be used (added to the `~/.Xresources` file):

```
URxvt*highlightColor:       #000000
URxvt*highlightTextColor:   #D75F00
```

Here's the explanation:

> ```
>    highlightColor: colour
>        If set, use the specified colour as the background for highlighted
>        characters. If unset, use reverse video.
>
>    highlightTextColor: colour
>        If set and highlightColor is set, use the specified colour as the
>        foreground for highlighted characters.
> ```

And now the selected text on fully transparent window looks like this:

[image: photo]

Comment: This makes selected text readable, however actual reverse video is still unreadable.